# Snake Game keep adding food and removing

Tags: python, pygame

i created a snake game and i have one problem in function food() it keep adding food on screen and removing it i don't know how to fix this i tried with food_statement like = "wait" when there's a food in screen and draw when it's not food can you help me code is working properly until hit food function?

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game by Joelinton')
blue=(0,0,255)
x_change = 0.2
y_change = 0.2
x = 400
y = 250

def creatingsnake():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,blue,[x,y,20,20])
def gameover():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 100)
    text = font.render('Game Over', True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(text, (250, 250))
def food():
    foodx = random.randint(0,750)
    foody = random.randint(0,550)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,blue,[foodx,foody,20,20])




running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= x_change
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += x_change
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= y_change
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += y_change
    if x < 0 or x > 780 or y < 0 or y > 580:
        gameover()
        running = False 
        time.sleep(1)    
    food()
    creatingsnake()


    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`food` is called in each frame. Thus, when the coordinates are generated in the function 'food', new random coordinates are generated in each frame. You must set the coordinates of the food once before the application loop:

```py
foodx = random.randint(0,750)
foody = random.randint(0,550)

def food():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,blue,[foodx,foody,20,20])

running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    food()
    creatingsnake()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @Joelinton Because `food` is called in every frame and so you create new random coordinates in every frame.